# Error the constructor in DownloadImageTask on BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, baseadapter

i have any problem, i find error in LogCat, why it could happen? xml can't be converted to JSONObject, any wrong with my code?

Content JSON

```
{"datamenu":[{"idmenu":"1","judulfilm":"Transfomers : Age Of Extinction","genre":" Action | Adventure | Sci-Fi","stdrfilm":"Michael Bay","pemainfilm":"Mark Wahlberg, Nicola Peltz, Jack Reynor, Kelsey Grammer, Stanley Tucci","rilisfilm":" 27 June 2014","durasifilm":"165 Menit","sinopsisfilm":"Empat tahun setelah film ketiga, pemerintah Amerika Serikat tidak lagi mempercayai para Transformer. Mereka memberi upah perburuan besar-besaran untuk memusnahkan mereka termasuk para Autobot. Seorang mekanik dan putrinya membuat penemuan yang mengarah kepada para Autobot, Decepticon, sehingga seorang pejabat pemerintah menjadi paranoid kepada mereka.\r\n\r\nKetika manusia menemukan teknologi Transformers purbakala, mereka menciptakan para Transformer miliknya sendiri, tetapi para Transformer yang baru dikembangkan segera menyadari dan akhirnya mengembangkan kesadaran dirinya, mereka mulai untuk memusnahkan umat manusia dan juga sisa-sisa para Autobot yang dibutuhkan untuk melindungi dunia dari kehancuran.","picfilm":"tf.jpg","idkategori":"2"}]}
```

### LogCat :

```
07-17 07:51:29.751: W/System.err(2263): org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-17 07:51:29.751: W/System.err(2263):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-17 07:51:29.751: W/System.err(2263):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
07-17 07:51:29.751: W/System.err(2263):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.film.JSONParser.getObject(JSONParser.java:84)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.film.AmbilData.doInBackground(AmbilData.java:55)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-17 07:51:29.755: W/System.err(2263):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-17 07:51:29.763: W/EGL_genymotion(2263): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-17 07:51:29.931: W/EGL_genymotion(2263): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

### Config.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db= "menufilm";

mysql_connect ($host,$username,$password) or die ("GAGAL");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("database tidak ada");

?>
```

### menu_service.php

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$json = array ();

$kategori=$_POST['kategori'];


$sqlselect="SELECT * FROM tb_menu WHERE idkategori=$kategori";
$hasil = mysql_query($sqlselect);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($hasil)){
            $menu[]=$row;
    }
    if (is_array($menu)) {
            $json['datamenu']=$menu;
            echo json_encode($json);
    }
?>
```

### Activity_main_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_custom_listview" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### item_custom_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.film.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/posterfilm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jdl_film"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/medium_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rls_film"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_view" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### ClientToSerever.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;



public class ClientToServer {
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30*1000;
    private static HttpClient client;
    static FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    static String sResponse;


    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        if (client == null) {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams parameterHttp = 
client.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(parameterHttp, 
                                HTTP_TIMEOUT);
                    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout (parameterHttp, 
HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return client;
    }

    public static String eksekusiHttpPost (String url,
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters)
throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient ();
            HttpPost req = new HttpPost (url);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new
UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            req.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse respon = client.execute(req);
            in = new BufferedReader (new
InputStreamReader(respon.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer ("");
            String line = "";
            String NL =
System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String hasil =sb.toString();
            return hasil;
        } finally {
            if (in !=null) {
                    in.close();
            }
        }
    }


    public static String eksekusiHttpGet (String url) throws
Exception {
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                HttpClient hc = getHttpClient ();
                HttpGet req = new HttpGet ();
                req.setURI(new URI(url));
                HttpResponse  resp = hc.execute(req);
                in = new BufferedReader (new
InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = 
System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while((line = in.readLine())!= null){
                        sb.append(line + NL);
                }
                in.close();
                String hasil =sb.toString();
                return hasil;
            } finally{
                if(in != null){
                    in.close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

### AmbilData.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    private JSONParser jsonparser;
    ArrayList<String> d;
    JsonObjectResult jobres;
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public void init(Context c, JsonObjectResult jres, String kategori,
            String url) {
        this.context = c;
        this.jobres = jres;

        AmbilData ad = this;
        ad.execute(url, kategori, "");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Retrieve Data", "aaa");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... parameter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONObject jsobj = null;
        String url = (String) parameter[0];
        String kat = (String) parameter[1];
        Log.i("url", url);
        Log.i("kat", kat);
        jsonparser = new JSONParser();
        List<NameValuePair> datajson = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        datajson.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kategori", kat));
        try {
            jsobj = jsonparser.getObject(url, "POST", datajson);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsobj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        if (result != null) {
            JSONObject js = (JSONObject) result;
            jobres.gotJsonObject(js);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class JsonObjectResult {
        public abstract void gotJsonObject(JSONObject jobject);
    }

}
```

### JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is;
    String json;

    JSONObject object;

    public JSONObject getObject(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> value)  throws IOException {

        if(method == "POST"){
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }else if(method == "GET"){
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String param = URLEncodedUtils.format(value, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + param;
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = client.execute(get);
                is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            object = null;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }

}
```

### MenuBaseAdapter.java

```
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<EntitasFilm> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String urlpic = "http://192.168.43.24/menufilm/";

    Bitmap bm;

    public MenuBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EntitasFilm> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int p) {
        return searchArrayList.get(p);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int p) {
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int p, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_custom_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.judul = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.jdl_film);
            holder.rilis = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rls_film);
            holder.pic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.posterfilm);
            // holder.deskripsi = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.d);
            new DownloadImageTask(holder.pic).execute(urlpic
                    + searchArrayList.get(p).getPicFilm());
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.judul.setText(searchArrayList.get(p).getJudulFilm());
        holder.rilis.setText(searchArrayList.get(p).getRilisFilm());
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView judul, rilis;
        ImageView pic;

    }

    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 72, 72, true);
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

whether is something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :

```
public void DownloadImageTask (ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
}
```

To this

```
public DownloadImageTask (ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
}
```

Don't use the keyword `void`. :)

Comment: Thanks its work, but i have any problem, i find error in LogCat "org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" why it could happen? @Slyzz

Comment: This error is not in this code. This error is because you try to parse a XML value into JSON and you can't because XML is not equal to JSON. Close this subject, and open a new one with the full logcat and code :D

Comment: i cant post again question :( you have email? please help me ... i can't run my application in normal, tomorrow my project must be submitted to my lecture @Slyzz

Comment: Why did you can't post again ? You launch your app only today for tomorrow. Edit this subject so.. But I have already said to you that you try to parse XML into JSON. So change your API to send JSON, or change your app to parse XML into XML :)

Comment: oya, I can edit this post, I forgot, sorry I am a newbie here, please help me, I've edited my post @Slyzz

Comment: Try to add this `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in your php file (first line).

Comment: still the same :( @Slyzz

Comment: I've edited my post again @Slyzz now with config.php

Comment: What is the output of your API ? Content and header.

Comment: Yes, content and header listview (Image and Text) @Slyzz but the content can't displayed cause the error :(

Comment: What is the output of your API ? Content and header. When you did a HTTP Request, with a browser.

Comment: in my edited post, i enter the content JSON and ClietToServer.java, i creat database in which text and image.jpg , so i convert to listview. @Slyzz